# how many events can be created with mysql events?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

i have many recurring data-centric tasks that i want to use mysql events. I am wondering how many events?

thanks.

Comment: If you think you need to create so many scheduled events that you may run out of the number of events, then you are doing something terribly wrong!

Comment: i am looking for a max number for example 100 , 1000 ,.. @Shadow